# Can I use "leap" alone, meaning "leap of faith"

Tags: word-meaning

This is a Merriam Webster definition for "leap":

> : a choice made in an area of ultimate concern
> *a leap of faith*

In the movie "The Batman" I saw someone say:

> Are you sure this isn't a leap?

Edit:(some more context asked for in the comments)
The scene occurs after Batman received a cipher from a criminal who left it for him, and which, after solving it, reads "DRIVE". He takes commissioner Gordon with whom he works on this case, to a multilevel parking garage that belonged to a murdered victim, near which the cipher was found.They are entering the garage and looking at the cars when Gordon says to Batman:

Where to even start?

You sure this isn’t a leap? “Drive” could mean anything.

is this just an ellipsis of the phrase "leap of faith" ?
Can I say "leap" meaning "leap of faith"?

Comment: If you say just "leap" by itself it doesn't necessarily mean "leap of faith".  More context would be needed to say if that's what was meant in the movie.  The dictionary doesn't mean that "leap" *means* "leap of faith", it just means that the word is used in that phrase with the meaning "a choice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell what the person meant without any context, but it seems as if that is what he or she meant.

Yes, you can omit "of faith" if the meaning is clear. However, you better make sure that there is no ambiguity, because otherwise people will be left scratching. (Their heads, I mean.)

---

Edit based on updated question: It now appears that Commissioner Gordon may mean "leap of faith". He and Batman are placing their faith in the idea that "drive" means "drive to the parking garage". However, he also might mean ["leap of logic"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leap-of-logic). Either interpretation would work in this context.

Comment: I added some, more context, as asked. Can anyone confirm now that "leap" in fact , means "leap of faith" ?

Comment: @StaticBounce I updated my answer.